# How can I remove a screenshot from the background rotation?

Tags: steam

How can I stop a screenshot from showing up in the Steam Library's background rotation?

I have tried deleting the screenshot but for some reason it's still showing up.

Comment: Have you ... tried restarting Steam? This really shouldn't be happening.

Answer (score 1):

Did you delete the screenshot from the cloud or from your local system?  The screenshots used for the background of that page are chosen at random from your local screenshots.  You can manage those by scrolling to the bottom of the game page and clicking on "View Screenshot Library".  That section will not appear if you don't have any local screenshots.

Your cloud screenshots can be managed from your profile, but deleting it from the cloud will not delete it from the machine that originally took the screenshot.  To delete it from both places at once, use the "View Screenshot Library" method (above) and check the box that says "Delete from Steam Cloud as well".

If you delete the currently visible screenshot it will not change until you select another game and come back (or restart Steam).